# using array.findIndex() on state in React

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, filtering, state

So I am new to react and I need a bit of help. I am working on a form that takes in several values and am currently testing a function `assignAtribute`, which takes in the name of the input element and uses it to update the state of an array called `currentRecipe` (see below).

```
 assignAttribute = (ident) => {
    var x = document.getElementById(ident).name;
    var holder = this.state.currentRecipe;
    var temp = null;

    var check = holder[x].findIndex(() => {return this.state[x]});

    check == -1 ? console.log('ok') : console.log('already exists')

    console.log(check)

    x == 'title' ?  temp = update(holder, {[x]: {$set: this.state[x] }}) 
    : x == 'ingredients' ? temp = update(holder, {[x]: {$push: [this.state[x]] }}) 
    : temp = update(holder, {[x]: {$push: [this.state[x]] }})

    holder = temp
    this.setState({ currentRecipe: holder})
    console.log(this.state[x])
    console.log(holder[x])

}
```

I am having an issue with it:

I want to filter the inputs so there are no duplicates so I am using a function inside that uses `array.findIndex()` to check it. When I look at the console output, I am not getting the output that matches the situation.

Thanks in advance,

Ben

Answer (score 0):

You're using `Array.prototype.findIndex` wrong. 
Instead of:

```
var check = holder[x].findIndex(() => {return this.state[x]})
```

it should be:

```
var check = holder[x].findIndex(el => el === this.state[x])
```

Aside from it I need a better context. I don't know what's the structure of `holder` variable and this:

```
x == 'title' ?  temp = update(holder, {[x]: {$set: this.state[x] }}) 
    : x == 'ingredients' ? temp = update(holder, {[x]: {$push: [this.state[x]] }}) 
    : temp = update(holder, {[x]: {$push: [this.state[x]] }})
```

is completely unreadable.

Answer (score 0):

```
assignAttribute = (ident) => {
    var x = document.getElementById(ident).name;
    var holder = this.state.currentRecipe;
    var temp = null;

    // Check for duplicates
    var check = holder[x].findIndex(item => item === this.state[x]);

    if (check === -1) {
        console.log('ok');

        // Update holder based on the type of input
        x === 'title' ? temp = update(holder, { [x]: { $set: this.state[x] } })
            : x === 'ingredients' ? temp = update(holder, { [x]: { $push: [this.state[x]] } })
                : temp = update(holder, { [x]: { $push: [this.state[x]] } });

        // Update state
        this.setState({ currentRecipe: temp });
    } else {
        console.log('already exists');
    }

    console.log(check);
    console.log(this.state[x]);
    console.log(holder[x]);
}
```